# How to use ADOBE SDK to write a "hello world" program in java script

Tags: adobe

How to use ADOBE SDK ? I'm very new to Adobe API's. I have installed adobe SDK, but i don't know how to use it with Visual Studio. A "hello World" program is really helpful for me.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Visual Studio 8". What are you referring to?

Comment: We can write adobe plug-ins in adobe SDK using VB or VC++ or Java script. I'm looking for a sample "hello world" program or sample steps to follow. Say i need to find programatically number of pages in the pdf file using adobe sdk.

Comment: What is it that you are calling "Visual Studio 8"? There is no product with that name.

Comment: u must be joken' right !

Comment: @mandy: no, I'm not. Do you mean Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: @mandy: thanks. The problem with using abbreviations is that different people use different abbreviations to mean different things. For instance, Visual Studio 2008 is version 9 of Visual Studio.